# Script retorna un dato System.IO.DirectoryInfo en lugar del string cuando explicitamente debe retornar el string

Tags: powershell

Tengo el siguiente script; el cual la opcion 1 y 2 funcionan correctamente, pero la opcion 3, en la que se espera que el usuario coloque el nombre del directorio no funciona...

**Este es mi script:**

```
function Set-Destination {
    param (
        [string]$dockroot
    )
    $sourceFile = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/docker/tpl/public/index.php"
    $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/project/$dockroot"
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $destinationPath -ItemType Directory
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $destinationPath
}

function Get-DirectoryRoot {
    Write-Host "`n Set your DocumentRoot directory."  -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host " You have requested the configuration of custom URLs:"
    Write-Host "`n => 1. Base to (/)        Like: Apache, CodeIgniter"
    Write-Host " => 2. Base to (/public)  Like: Laravel, Symfony"
    Write-Host " => 3. Set your Custom    Like: Yii (web), CakePHP (webroot)"
    $choice = Read-Host " Choose option 1, 2, 3 (Press any key for default: 1)"
    if ($choice -eq "2") {
        $sourcePath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/docker/tpl/public"
        $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/project"
        Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destinationPath -Recurse
        return "/public"
    } elseif($choice -eq "3") {
        Get-AddCyanLine
        Write-Host "`n Set your Custom Name Folder."  -ForegroundColor "Red"
        Write-Host " Note: if it not exists, it would be created."
        Write-Host " ==>" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "Red"
        $dockroot = Read-Host
        Set-Destination -dockroot $dockroot
        return "/$dockroot"
    } else {
        $sourceFile = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/docker/tpl/public/index.php"
        $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/project"
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Path $destinationPath -ItemType Directory
        }
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $destinationPath
        return "/"
    }
}

$dockroot = Get-DirectoryRoot

Write-Host "Retorno: $dockroot"

Pause
```

el objetivo es retornar el string dado por el usuario, en lugar de eso me retorna un objeto `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` y cuando lo imprimo me sale esto en formato de texto:

```
C:\Users\sdfgdsfgds\OneDrive\Documents\DockerStack\project\app /app
```

cuando solo se espera el texto que ingrese: `/app`

He realizado pruebas con eliminar `Set-Destination` que al parecer es quien interfiere y entonces funciona pero no se que en esa funcion esta interfiriendo y por que altera el valor de $dockroot.

El código que daña el valor de `$dockroot` es esta parte:

```
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $destinationPath -ItemType Directory
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer `New-Item` genera un `output` que altera la variable `$dockroot` estoy casi seguro que esto se trata de un funcionamiento no esperado o un bug, el hecho de tener que descartar/desechar el output de `New-Item` de manera manual como que no tiene mucho sentido:

```
function Set-Destination {
    param (
        [string]$dockroot
    )
    $sourceFile = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/docker/tpl/public/index.php"
    $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/project/$dockroot"
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $destinationPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Considero esto un `workaround` y no una respuesta definitiva... si alguien mas le sirve les dejo esta respuesta.

Comment: No conviene asignar un valor a la variable $null.  $null es reservada para designar un valor nulo.

Comment: @WalterMitty cambiale el nombre a la variable y listo :)